# Node Socket.IO/Apache doesn't free memory after shutdown

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache, socket.io

I have a normal setup with multiple cluster. When reaching 10K concurrent connections with websocket, it reaches around 99% memory usage and then shuts down due to low memory.

Now the issue is, that if I kill the background job of the node app, it doesn't free the memory. I'll have to restart the apache service `httpd` to free it.

I'm running the app with manual gc  `node --expose_gc app.js` with an interval of 1000ms. It's a `socket.io` node app, using `websocket` transport. Implemented the cluster example from the official docs, nothing changed!

CentOS7 with Apache, using cluster for multiple nodes along with reverse proxy. My setup has around 25GB of RAM free for socket.io's usage.

Any ideas how to free the memory? The service is shut down, and nothing gets saved, I'm not using any storing variables.

Apache's config

```
SSLEngine on
      ProxyRequests off
      ProxyPass "/websocket/socket" balancer://nodes_ws/
      ProxyPassReverse "/websocket/socket" balancer://nodes_ws/
      ProxyTimeout 3

Header add Set-Cookie "BlazocketServer=sticky.%{BALANCER_WORKER_ROUTE}e; path=/" env=BALANCER_ROUTE_CHANGED
      <Proxy "balancer://nodes_polling">
        BalancerMember "https://localhost:3000" route=app01
        BalancerMember "https://localhost:3001" route=app02
        BalancerMember "https://localhost:3002" route=app03
        ProxySet stickysession=BlazocketServer
      </Proxy>

      <Proxy "balancer://nodes_ws">
          BalancerMember "ws://localhost:3000" route=app01
          BalancerMember "ws://localhost:3001" route=app02
          BalancerMember "ws://localhost:3002" route=app03
          ProxySet stickysession=BlazocketServer
      </Proxy>

      RewriteEngine On
      #RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=polling
      #RewriteRule /(.*)$ http://localhost:3000/$1 [P]


      RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket [NC]
      RewriteRule /(.*) balancer://nodes_ws/$1 [P,L]

      RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=polling
      RewriteRule /(.*) balancer://nodes_polling/$1 [P,L]

<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
  ServerLimit                10000
  StartServers               600
  MinSpareServers            100
  MaxSpareServers            500
  MaxClients                 10000
  MaxConnectionsPerChild     10000

  #MinSpareThreads           4500
  #MaxSpareThreads           9000
  #ThreadLimit               640
  #ThreadsPerChild           3000

  #MaxRequestWorkers          5120
  #MaxRequestsPerChild        20000
</IfModule>
```

Socket's app.js

```
import express from "express";
const app = express();

import * as http from "http"
const httpServer = http.createServer(app);

import {Server} from "socket.io";
import cluster from "cluster"
import os from "os"
import { setupMaster, setupWorker } from "@socket.io/sticky"
import { createAdapter, setupPrimary } from "@socket.io/cluster-adapter"


http.globalAgent.maxSockets = Infinity;
httpServer.maxRequestsPerSocket = Infinity;

const numCPUs = os.cpus().length;

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  console.log(`Master ${process.pid} is running`);
  // Setup master worker
  setupMaster(httpServer, {
    loadBalancingMethod: "least-connection",
  });
  // Establish it
  setupPrimary();

  cluster.setupMaster({
    serialization: "advanced",
  });

  // Listen on port 3000
  httpServer.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Started from master")
  })

  // Fork the workers of the cluster
  for (let i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }

  // Report any dead workers and fork it again
  cluster.on("exit", (worker) => {
    console.log(`Worker ${worker.process.pid} died`);
    cluster.fork();
  });

} else {
  console.log(`Worker ${process.pid} started`);

  // Setup the Socket.io instance
  const io = new Server(httpServer, {});

  // Establish the connection with the adapter and the worker's process
  io.adapter(createAdapter());
  setupWorker(io);


  // Setup the connection
  io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log(`#CONNECTION: ${socket.id} connected`)
  })
}
```

Comment: You have tagged `socket.io` and talked about `websockets` plus socket.io have a very little memory footprint, if you're using socket.io i think it could be the issue with you're algorithms, and not socket.io on it self

Comment: The node app is a socket.io instance, that's why I tagged it. `websocket` is the transport that I'm using for it. I have the basic template implementation of cluster from the `socket.io` docs and didn't change anything.

Comment: @Jaeger Just to be clear, your apache does not free the memory or the node.js process? How does your application stack/setup looks like? node.js running behind apache, configured as reverse proxy? Is the issue apache or node.js?

Comment: I've updated and included the files. Process is simple, node starts in background with 8 workers, concurrent increases via stress-load by `npx artillery run my-scenario.yml`, reaches 10K, RAM goes up to 95%. Now, I kill the stress-load and see the `disconnected` logs. After that, the RAM stays high, I try to kill the `node  app.js` process via `kill %1`. I wait, RAM is still high. I decide to restart `httpd` (apache), then RAM goes back to 2% (freed).

Comment: Answering your question about whether it's apache or node, I suspect it's via node due to the SO's questions that I've seen about the ram leaking issue.